# Geotools RPFTOCReader NegativeArraySizeException in reading raster

Tags: raster, gdal, java, geotools, rpf

*System: Eclipse IDE in Windows 10 VM Java 8*

**My code segment that the exception is being thrown:**

```
private void displayLayers(File rasterFile) throws Exception {
    Hints hints = new Hints();

    reader = new RPFTOCReader(rasterFile, hints);


    final MapContent map = new MapContent();
    map.setTitle("Jonathan's attempt");

    Style rasterStyle = createGreyscaleStyle();
    Layer rasterLayer = new GridReaderLayer(reader, rasterStyle);

    map.addLayer(rasterLayer);


    frame = new JMapFrame(map);
    frame.setSize(800, 600);
    frame.enableStatusBar(true);
    frame.enableToolBar(true);

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    menuBar.add(new JMenu("Raster"));

    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

the createGreyscaleStyle() method is the same one from [this tutorial](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/raster/image.html).

**Exception:**

```
    Jan 02, 2018 2:37:41 PM it.geosolutions.imageio.gdalframework.GDALUtilities loadGDAL
    INFO: GDAL Native Library loaded (version: 2.2.1)
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
        at it.geosolutions.imageio.gdalframework.GDALImageReader.readDatasetRaster(GDALImageReader.java:331)
        at it.geosolutions.imageio.gdalframework.GDALImageReader.read(GDALImageReader.java:952)
        at org.geotools.coverageio.RasterLayerResponse.readRaster(RasterLayerResponse.java:440)
        at org.geotools.coverageio.RasterLayerResponse.createCoverage(RasterLayerResponse.java:210)
        at org.geotools.coverageio.RasterLayerResponse.compute(RasterLayerResponse.java:180)
        at org.geotools.coverageio.BaseGridCoverage2DReader.requestCoverage(BaseGridCoverage2DReader.java:606)
        at org.geotools.coverageio.BaseGridCoverage2DReader.read(BaseGridCoverage2DReader.java:387)
        at org.geotools.raster.ImageLab.createGreyscaleStyle(ImageLab.java:189)
        at org.geotools.raster.ImageLab.displayLayers(ImageLab.java:107)
        at org.geotools.raster.ImageLab.getLayersAndDisplay(ImageLab.java:95)
        at org.geotools.raster.ImageLab.main(ImageLab.java:69)

    OpenGL Warning: crPixelCopy3D:  simply crMemcpy'ing from srcPtr to dstPtr
    OpenGL Warning: crPixelCopy3D:  simply crMemcpy'ing from srcPtr to dstPtr
    OpenGL Warning: crPixelCopy3D:  simply crMemcpy'ing from srcPtr to dstPtr
    OpenGL Warning: crPixelCopy3D:  simply crMemcpy'ing from srcPtr to dstPtr
    OpenGL Warning: crPixelCopy3D:  simply crMemcpy'ing from srcPtr to dstPtr
    OpenGL Warning: crPixelCopy3D:  simply crMemcpy'ing from srcPtr to dstPtr
    OpenGL Warning: crPixelCopy3D:  simply crMemcpy'ing from srcPtr to dstPtr
    OpenGL Warning: crPixelCopy3D:  simply crMemcpy'ing from srcPtr to dstPtr
```

**Tracking the stack trace**

The exception is thrown within the createGreyscaleStyle() method within my code (link to method is mentioned above) which is called from the Style object I attempt to make within my code excerpt. Within the createGreyscaleStyle(), the reader.read() function is called which eventually calls readDatasetRaster() (method in GDALImageReader).

[On line 327](https://github.com/geosolutions-it/imageio-ext/blob/master/library/gdalframework/src/main/java/it/geosolutions/imageio/gdalframework/GDALImageReader.java) of GDALImageReader the calculated bufferSize is -1173618688, dstWidth is 75264, dstHeight is 41472, and when pixels is first calculated it's -1173618688.

When I run gdalinfo on the A.TOC file I get a size that is 75264, 41472 so it looks like the reader is extracting accurate data.

**Problem:**
Don't know how to account for the negative value of bufferSize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image is too big, or the author of the code didn't expect it to be that big. In [GDALImageReader](https://github.com/geosolutions-it/imageio-ext/blob/master/library/gdalframework/src/main/java/it/geosolutions/imageio/gdalframework/GDALImageReader.java#L285) both `pixels` and `bufferSize` are integers and in Java MaxInt is 2,147,483,647. While your image size is `(75264×41472)` or `3,121,348,608` so it overflows and becomes negative.

This is a bug and you should raise a [bug report](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOT) and preferably a PR with the fix in too.

Comment: Is there a way to cut the data down and then stitch it back together? Also the link you sent went to jira for geoserver and not geotools (https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/projects/GEOT/issues/GEOT-5865?filter=allopenissues)--is it better to submit via geoserver the bug? Also what does the abbreviation PR mean?

Comment: It seems to pick randomly, I would say this was a GeoTools bug as it contains the code. - A PR is a Pull Request, you need to fork the GT repo make your changes push them to GitHub and then request that we pull them in.  http://docs.geotools.org/latest/developer/procedures/contribute.html